# Structuring a page with multiple views with backbone.js

Tags: layout, backbone.js, view, models

I've gone through various demos, examples and tutorials and still haven't find the right/best way to write the following structure:

When I get to a certain route I would like to render multiple views inside views that go down through three levels. So my basic structure would be like this -

- Container

  - Article

    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
  - Article

    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
  - Article

    - Section

      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
  - Article

    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
    - Section

      - Component
      - Component

Each view/model must be separate from each other as they may need to re-render. I've looked at layout manager, nestedModels and relationalModels but can't seem to get what I want. Is there a "right" way to create this type of layout and should I be using Collections.

Sorry for my lack of understanding. A complete newbie with a rather large ambitious project.

Comment: Backbone doesn't provide many assumptions on how you structure your code. As such there are plenty of ways of achieving the same goal and they are all "right".

Comment: Would you know how I would go about creating something like the structure above? I can never quite get it right. Started to drive me a bit crazy @JaredMcAteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MarionetteJS](http://marionettejs.com/), a plugin library for Backbone, will help you handling this kind of view nesting.

It provides Regions, Layout, CollectionView and ItemView that are great helpers in your situation.

Here is a really nice [tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/)[, part2](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/22/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks...had a quick look at this and looks like I'll be able to it with this. Does it allow nested models within other models? @Arnaud Rinquin

Comment: Hum, I don't think it's a good idea to nest Models. You'd better have references to another model but not have it nested.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will try out both marionette and layout manager and see what works best. Marionette seemed like a lot for what I need where as layout manager seemed slightly easier due to it only controlling the layout. @Arnaud Rinquin

Comment: You can use Marionette partially. Application, Regions, CollectionViews and ItemViews are very usefull (and you'd basically rewrite them in most of case).

Comment: Ok...I found the documentation didnt quite give me an example of what I was trying to do. But the documentation for layout manager did. I'm a complete newbie with backbone and application design so I have been going around and around in circles with this part of the app. Is there any chance you could show me an example of how to build the structure above using marionette please? Thanks for the help. @Arnaud Rinquin

Comment: I won't spend more time to help you but I hope this link will provide all the help you need : [Use cases for different views](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Use-cases-for-the-different-views). Also, be sure to read the [FAQ](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki)

Last hint : you should have 4 views : Articles, Article, Section, Component. Articles, Article and Section are CollectionView, Component is an ItemView.

Comment: I wrote something wrong in my last comment. Articles, Article, Section and Component should be CompositeViews (instead of collection view)

Comment: Thanks...the use cases was just what I wanted. Everything is completely explained there. Don't know how I missed that!thanks for all your help @Arnaud Rinquin

Comment: Hey Arnaud any chance you could have a look at this question i posted. dont know how to private message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090186/how-to-stop-the-touchend-event-firing-on-touchstart-with-backbone thanks @Arnaud Rinquin